# How to initialise a variable to a pointer of the camera component which is attached to the player

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

How do I initialize a variable to a pointer of the camera component which is attached to the player?

I have in my .h file a private member variable that I have declared as:

```
//player.h code
private: 
    UCameraComponent* Camera;
```

In my .cpp file, I am trying to get that and initialize it. I am basically just trying to find through code where the camera is stored in the player character.

Currently my .cpp looks like:

```
//player.cpp code
void APlayerCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    Camera = FindComponentByClass<UCameraComponent>();
}
```

Up until here, everything is working as it should. I have a function that is designed for camera movement (looking around using mouse) - and this is where the program crashes.

```
/player.cpp code
void APlayerCharacter::LookUp(float Value)
{

    FRotator DeltaRotation = FRotator::ZeroRotator;
    DeltaRotation.Pitch = Value * LookSensitivity;
    Camera->AddRelativeRotation(DeltaRotation);
}
```

There aren't any issues compiling but it's not working at all and just crashes the program (Unreal Engine 4).

Hopefully this question isn't worded too badly, I can be more specific if necessary but for now if anyone knows what I should do then that would be greatly appreciated.

--EDITED--

Extended the code, hopefully clarifies a bit more.

Comment: "and this is where the program crashes" -> I guess Camera is null. Did you trace the value of camera after the "FindComponentByClass" and in "LookUp" ?

Comment: @GarnetKane The most obvious possibility is that `Camera` is null. You should always check these things. Obviously the next question will be, why is it null?, but that's a different question.

Comment: @john hey perfect answer! that's exactly what it ended up being, and yeah it ended up being a question of why it was null, for some reason my code added in on the cpp Camera = FindComponentByClass<UCameraComponent*>(); with the **

Comment: @GarnetKane not sure if you're still experiencing this issue, but if so, when are you calling the `LookUp` function? Perhaps there's a race condition where `LookUp` is getting called before `BeginPlay`

Comment: @GarnetKane also is your camera component attached directory to the character in blueprints or is it attached to another component that is directly attached to the character?